# Django instances building up until crashes site (UPDATE: Redis deadlock HIGHLY suspected)

Tags: python, django, nginx, redis, deadlock

**See EDIT#2 below for likely root cause**

My Django threads/processes (same thing happens when using both 'method=threaded' and 'method=prefork'), every 10 mins or so, randomly build up like so:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ihuNR.png e.g lots of these processes:

`python ./manage.py runfcgi method=threaded host=localhost port=8888`

Then in a minute or so, the threads/processes build up enough to take out my site.

The site load is pretty minimal, but the traffic is fairly high, so I believe it's some sort of blocking issue.

Any ideas on how to solve, or even effectively debug this issue?
Thanks.

**EDIT:** I also use Redis a lot from many of my Django views. I'm now beginning to look into the possibility of a Redis deadlock issue being the root of the problem...

**EDIT#2:** I'm seeing that Redis gets pinned at 100% CPU when the issue starts, which makes me believe a  Redis deadlock of sorts is the core issue.

I also got this error:

"(error) LOADING Redis is loading the dataset in memory"

when trying to fully restart Redis via this commmand:

`./src/redis-cli flushall`

IMPORTANT: I'm using Redis 2.2.7 on a separate EC2 micro instance than my Django web application.

Comment: Are you using threads or processes anywhere?

Comment: Anywhere on the server? Yes, both threads and processes, for different things. Maybe I'm not understanding your question?

Comment: Sorry, I meant within django, once, I saw a case where a deadlock caused a lot of extra processes to get started.

Comment: How did you debug, or manage to get around that deadlock? Thanks!

Comment: Redis is single-threaded. A deadlock in Redis is not possible, because there is no lock.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out to be an obscure bug in Redis.

A Redis update, Redis 2.2.7 -> Redis 2.4.16 fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Threads and processes are two different things. The cause will most likely be threads if the entire site goes down.

Comment: I know threads and process are different things :/ I just pointed that out to show I've tried several different configurations.

Comment: Saw your edits: That response error could occur when the child thread & process attempts to connect to their parent after the parent restarts and or on start-up. If you have a multi-child single parent environment it will definitely cause network hick ups.

If your getting loads of these "Redis is loading the dataset in memory". Its probably due to child's loading data when the client isn't blocked, which could possibly cause a deadlock because its
trying to display data to the client whilst its reading it from memory.